# Journey Builder or Triggered Send with date sensitive send times

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

I would like to make a journey in journey builder. We have a series of events occurring throughout the year from March to September.

There are around 50 events.

In the seventh day leading up to the event, they need to receive 2 emails - a 7 day reminder, and a 1 day reminder.

We have the date of the event stored in the data extension as a column. I need to send people these emails based upon this date - for example,

> When Event_Date = Today + 7 days, Send Email 1
>
> When Event_Date = Today + 7 days, Send Email 2

The 'Wait' function doesn't give you much to work with as you can only choose static lengths of time, and if I set this up as a decision split, those who meet the criteria will get the email, but those who don't will go onto the No branch, and you can't loop them or make them wait until they do meet the criteria, apparently.

What would be a way around this?

Comment: Can you setup your journey only add records once the qualify for the 7 day email?  The journey would deploy the 1st email on day one; and then deploy the 2nd email on day 6 days later (or 1 day before the event).

Comment: David - you're a genius. That is such an easy way, I can't believe I hadn't thought of that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Since you are using a webform and there can be chances where registrants can register less than 7 days before the event as well, your journey flow should take care of this as well. As mentioned above, your entry criteria would make sure registrants enter the journey only before 7 days.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshKumar will the journey keep checking registrants every day and inject them once the date has come, or will it check them once, and then if they do not meet the critera, block them from entering?

Answer (score 0):

-Incase someone comes across this question:

Date based event as entry source will help you achieve the above request.

Before using this, you need to link the DE with the contact model (data designer)

Or
You can use Wait by attribute activity to wait based on a date field/attribute.